# Транслитерация Current URI в Permalink Manager Pro

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я использую плагин Permalink Manager Pro, чтобы добавлять в слаг дату из ACF-поля записи. В настройках Permalink Manager Pro включена опция "Use actual post/term titles (Force custom slugs)".

Когда я создаю запись и делаю заголовок на английском, то проблем нету. Но если заголовок на русском языке, то слаг получается также на русском.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы слаг автоматически был на английском? Плагины типа "Cyr-To-Lat" не помогают, они изменяют только Нативный слаг

Comment: Пожалуйста, установите основной плагин cyr2lat https://wordpress.org/plugins/cyr2lat/ (остальные - форки от него) и опишите последовательность действий, которые приводят к картинке выше. ЛУчше, если эта последовательность будет описана с Permalink Manager Lite (у меня нет Pro).

Comment: Действия по-порядку

1. Запустил новый проект с вордпрессом

2. Добавил и кативировал только 2 плагина cyr2lat и Permalink Manager Lite

3. В настройках Permalink Manager Lite (settings) поставил галочку у "Show "Native slug" field" и в строке "Use actual post/term titles (Force custom slugs)" поставил YES (там еще есть подсказка - If enabled, the slugs in the default custom permalinks will be recreated from the post titles.)

4. Создаю новую запись, название указываю по-русски

И получается слаг по-русски (из-за YES в 3 пункте)

Answer (score 1):

У меня на WP 5.2.2 с Gutenberg несколько иное поведение. Тем не менее, попробуйте добавить такой код в functions.php вашей темы

```
/**
 * Permalink Manager filter.
 *
 * @param string  $permalink     Permalink.
 * @param WP_Post $post          Post.
 * @param string  $old_permalink Old permalink.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function my_permalink_manager_filter_final_post_permalink( $permalink, $post, $old_permalink ) {
    if ( class_exists( 'Cyr_To_Lat_Main' ) ) {
        return $old_permalink;
    }

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'permalink_manager_filter_final_post_permalink', 'my_permalink_manager_filter_final_post_permalink', 10, 3 );
```

Дайте знать, получилось ли решить проблему. Если да, возможно мы добавим этот хук в cyr2lat, чтобы проблема решалась автоматически.

Если установлен classic editor, то даже этот код выше не нужен. Вот результат создания записи на WP 5.2.2 при активированных плагинах classic editor, permalink manager lite и cyr2lat.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я еще добавил classic editor. Нет, увы, не помогло

Comment: Ну вот, оказывается вы забыли сказать про classic editor. И в самом деле, картинка в вашем вопросе может быть получена только с classic editor. Ещё что вы упустили? У меня с classic editor всё работает, даже без кода в моём ответе, см. картинку.

Comment: Мой косяк, виноват. Да, вы правы, такое происходит именно когда включен classic editor. Я протестировал разные варианты: 1. Вашего кода нет, CE выключен - на странице всех записей и в редактировании записи слаг кириллицей. 2. Вашего кода нет, CE включен - на странице всех записей и в редактировании записи слаг кириллицей. 3. Ваш код есть, CE выключен - все слаги латиницей (даже у тех записей что были созданы ранее кроме "Привет, Мир!"). 4. Ваш код есть, CE включен - на странице всех записей слаг на латинице (при наведении на "Перейти"), на странице редактировании записи слаг на кириллице

Comment: Можно ли решить данный вопрос с использованием Classic Editor?

Comment: Я не понимаю, в чём вопрос. Подозреваю, что у вас не чистая установка WP с нуля. Вы же видите на моей картинке, что всё работает, причём без моего кода.

Comment: Да нет же, я создал новый "проект" в openserver, загрузил вордпресс и эти три плагина: Classic Editor, Cyr-To-Lat, Permalink Manager Lite

Comment: В принципе, как только изменил в настройках Permalink Manager строку "Use actual post/term titles (Force custom slugs)" на "NO", стало показывать как нужно. Есть правда, один нюанс, но это уже для другого вопроса. Спасибо, что уделили время!